# Fake click inside the iframe is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some external website which i am loading using iFrame. And i am trying to implement fake click inside the iframe.

Here is my code

```
window.load(function(){
 $('#book-iframe').contents().find('.Home').trigger("click");

});
```

also if try `$('#book-iframe').contents().find('.Home').trigger("click");` code on browser console it works very well.

Any suggestions

Comment: Not possible. :)

Comment: That would be a security nightmare.

Comment: You should get an error in your console saying that you cannot do what you are trying to do

Comment: There is no error in console.

Comment: $('#book-iframe').contents().length is 0, right?

Comment: No it's 1 .....

Comment: It's strange you have not this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://theexternalsite" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: No. iframe code is also sitting on same server.

Comment: What about $('#book-iframe').contents().find('.Home').click() ?

Comment: not working. :(

Comment: if i run on browser console it's working

Comment: $('#book-iframe').contents().find('.Home').html() - can you paste the result here, I am curious.

Comment: i dont have content in class .Home,  it's showing " " when i hit html()  command first time but later it is showing undefined

Comment: $('#book-iframe').contents().find('.Home').length is 0? Are you sure you have the .Home class in your iframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify iframes only if they are from the **same parent domain.**

With external website you could do that only if:

1) You have **direct access** to the source code

2) You have found security vulnerability an [XSS (Cross Site Scripting)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is independent of the frame that is displaying it.

To apply changes (styles / content / etc.) to the iFrame page you need to edit that page.

Comment: Your this answer should be in comment.